# How do I programmatically reorder my jQuery multiselect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, multi-select

I'm using [ui.multiselect.js](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/) to style my multiselects. Both sides are draggable and the left side is sortable, and that cannot change. What I want to do is hit a button, and have that button move four of my selections (call them `a, b, c, d`) from the right to the left, displaying (and being stored within `$('#mySelect').val()`) in the order `a, d, b, c`.

I can get the selections to move to the left easily enough, but changing their order is stumping me. I've told the `_moveOptionNode(item)` function to echo out its relevant contents, but then I realized that since it only accepts one parameter that's not very useful. That function makes calls optionally to `.insertAfter()` and `.prependTo()`, but so far calling those directly has yielded me no luck either.

I know from past experience that the order of the selected options within `$('#mySelect').val()` will update along with the visuals, and that's important to what I'm doing, but I also know that with the current build of `ui.multiselect.js` I cannot update the order of `$('#mySelect').val()` first. So I clearly need a way to either mimic dragging an option, or get it to start out sorted how I want it in the first place.

I'm still working on this, but so far I haven't had any success, and I would greatly appreciate any help this community can offer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the way to do this is by manipulating HTML elements, rather than by affecting the multiselect ui element. I accomplished it with these two lines of code:

```
$(".selected li:contains('d')", $($('#mySelect').parent()[0])).insertAfter($(".selected li:contains('a')", $($('#mySelect').parent()[0])))

$("#mySelect option[value='d']").insertAfter($("#mySelect option[value='a']"))
```

There is, of course, an obvious weakness to this method, since it is going to move every visual element that contains the letter d and copy it after every visual element that contains the letter a, but fixing that will just be a matter of changing how I select the elements. The overall method is what was really important here, and now that I've got that, the rest is cake.

Edit: Here's my final code:

```
var previtem = null;
var prevvalue = '';
$.each(values, function(i, item) {
    var text = $("#mySelect option[value='"+item+"']").text();
    $('#mySelect').multiselect("select", text);
    $.each($('.selected li:contains('+text+')', $($('#mySelect').parent()[0])), function(i, item) {
        if ($(item).text() == text) {
            // We only move it if it's not the first one in
            // By definition it won't be moved to the start, so this will always work
            if (previtem != null) {
                $(item).insertAfter(previtem);
            }
            previtem = $(item);
        }
    });
    // Again, only move the option if it's not the first one in
    if (prevvalue != '')
        $("#mySelect option[value='"+item+"']").insertAfter($("#mySelect option[value='"+prevvalue+"']"));
    prevvalue = item;
});
```